# How to get only one of two repeating values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

#### The Issue

In simple terms, I am trying to set a formula for an alternating pattern. The issue I keep running into is the fact that there are two alternating values, and Google Sheets doesn't like to repeat only one of those values without the other.

I have created an example sheet to demonstrate my issue. In `Column A`, a date is input. `Column B` and `Column C` then autofill with the day of the week and AM or PM respectively. Every other value in `Column C` alternates between AM and PM. I am trying to set it up so that the row is blank until a value in input in `Column A`. The issue comes when there is an odd number of Dates in `Column A`. Note that the alternating AM/PM pattern will never change.

#### What I've Tried

[image: Sheet Example]

As seen in the image above, there are three main methods that I have tried. The data in `C2:C8` is the desired result.

> **Method 1:**
>
> `E2`: `=transpose(split({rept(join(";",{"AM";" "})&";",(roundup(counta(A2:A9)/2)))},";"))`
>
> `F3`: `=transpose(split({rept(join(";",{"PM";" "})&";",(counta(A2:A9)/2))},";"))`
>
> These formulas work separately, and best represent what I am trying to accomplish, but I have not found a way to combine them to work together in one column.

> **Method 2:**
>
> `H2`: `=transpose(split({rept(join(";",{"AM";"PM"})&";",(roundup(counta(A2:A9)/2)))},";"))`
>
> This is essentially the same as Method 1, but put into one formula. The issue here is that Google Sheets doesn't like to repeat half a number of times. So if the number of times to repeat (`counta(A2:A9)/2`) contains a half (i.e. 3.5), it will still round down to the nearest whole number.

> **Method 3:**
>
> `J2`: `=ArrayFormula(TEXT(SEQUENCE(3),"")&{"AM";"PM"})`
>
> This one appeared most promising to me because when incrementing by one, it added one row, but I quickly ran into the issue where if I went over a sequence number of 2, it threw the error `Array arguments to CONCAT are of different size`.

#### **References**

I have used various search terms and websites to try to solve this, and have yet to find something that works. I may be missing something very simple, though, and hopefully this is a quick solution.

> Example Sheet:
>
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3EtptFLfDHpAQ8AR6Lwa01dSpJ3Cy8MTX1_OjHExSc/edit?usp=sharing

> All my formulas are derived from the websites below:
>
> [REPT Function in Google Sheets](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/rept-function/)
>
> [How to Repeat Multiple Columns N Times in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/repeat-multiple-columns-n-times-in-google-sheets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete everything in Col C (including the header) and place this formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"AM/PM"; IF(A2:A="",,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))=1,"AM","PM"))})`

The `COUNTIFS` finds the number of matches for the date "up to this row" for every row. Since that count will (or should) only ever be a 1 or a 2, the `IF` makes easy work of assigning "AM" or "PM" accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it is enough to use `ISEVEN` function to alternate by rows:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A,CHOOSE(ISEVEN(ROW(A2:A))+1,"PM","AM"),))
```

[image]